# Soundcloud: single_active parameter in HTML5 widget?

Tags: html, parameters, widget, soundcloud

is there any chance the HTML5 will be updated soon with the single_active parameter to allow simultaneous audio tracks playing in a page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually already is an option of the HTML5 widget. You disable it like this:

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/84984139&single_active=false
```

Note the `&single_active` GET param added to the widget’s src